# Spring Batch - Issue with PageSize in JdbcPagingItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Hi We are working on a spring batch, which processes all the SKUs  in SKU table and send a request to inventory system to get the inventory details. To send to invetory details we need to send 100 SKI ids at a time so we have set the pageSize as 100.

in the reader log:
we see

> SELECT * FROM (SELECT S_ID ,S_PRNT_PRD,SQ, ROWNUM as TMP_ROW_NUM FROM
>   XXX_SKU WHERE SQ>=:min and SQ <=:max ORDER BY SQ ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <=
>   100]

But we observe in the WRITER that is for certain time 100 SKU are sent and for certain requests only 1 SKU is sent.

```
public void write(List<? extends XXXPagingBean> pItems) throws XXXSkipItemException {
if (mLogger.isLoggingDebug()) {
mLogger.logDebug("XXXInventoryServiceWriter.write() method STARTING, ItemsList size:{0}" +pItems.size());
}
....
....
}
```

- pageSize and commitInterval is set to 100 (are these suppose to be same?)
- sortKey (SEQ_ID) should be same a column use in partitiner?

Bean configurations in XML:

```
<!-- InventoryService Writer configuration -->

<bean id="inventoryGridService" class="atg.nucleus.spring.NucleusResolverUtil" factory-method="resolveName">
<constructor-arg value="/com/XXX/gigaspaces/inventorygrid/service/InventoryGridService" />
</bean>

<bean id="inventoryWriter" class="com.XXX.batch.integrations.XXXXXX.XXXXInventoryServiceWriter" scope="step">
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="batchDsTemplate"></property>
<property name="inventoryGridService" ref="inventoryGridService" />
</bean>

<bean id="pagingReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" scope="step">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="queryProvider">
<bean id=" productQueryProvider" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="selectClause" value="select S_ID ,S_PRNT_PRD" />
<property name="fromClause" value="from XXX_SKU" />
<property name="sortKey" value="SEQ_ID" />
<property name="whereClause" value="SEQ_ID>=:min and SEQ_ID &lt;=:max"></property>
</bean>
</property>
<property name="parameterValues">
<map>
<entry key="min" value="#{stepExecutionContext[minValue]}"></entry>
<entry key="max" value="#{stepExecutionContext[maxValue]}"></entry>
</map>
</property>
<property name="pageSize" value="100" />
<property name="rowMapper">
<bean class="com.XXX.batch.integrations.endeca.XXXPagingRowMapper"></bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What's the reason for sending the SKUs in groups of 100? Are they related to each other in some way?

Comment: this is a inventory call and restriction is we can send only 100 SKU to the service.

Comment: Do you have to send exactly 100 SKUs at a time, or can you send any number that is 100 or below? If it is the second case, then why is the writer's behaviour a problem?

Comment: Did you get this to working in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your whereClause from the `productQueryProvider` bean definition and get rid of your `parameterValues` and it should work. The `PagingQueryProvider` takes care of paging automatically for you. There's no need to do that manually yourself.